# Appending www in url with https using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this issue on Firefox and not on chrome. When user enters URL of my https site without `www.` , it should append `www` in my URL.

Right now, Firefox shows this error:

> Your connection is not secure

When user enters URL of my site without **www.**
I tried different `.htaccess` rules but none of them work. What should be the correct way of appending `www` in URL?

Below are two options that I tried but none of them worked:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Second option:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: can you share your `.htaccess` rules here  ? it's might help to correct answer @FarazAleem

Comment: Below are two options i tried but none of them worked: 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: put in question not in comment  @FarazAleem

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you can't redirect visitors on a HTTPS URL until they have a valid HTTPS session. So your certificate needs to be valid for non-www or the security warning will always appear and the redirect will not be issued.

This will redirect anyone who is not on `https://www.` to that. Just remember, as I said above, the certificate must be valid on https before the redirect can be issued if you don't want the warning.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Just replace `www.example.com` as appropriate.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but why it is properly redirecting on Chrome ie if user enters url with http and without www , chrome is appending www and also redirecting to https which is ideally what i want.

Comment: Yes, visiting on http will work fine and the redirect will happen. The only problem is visiting https with non-www.

Comment: I am only concerned when user enters https , it should append www and should not give "Your connection is not secure" message. I tried above rule and changed the domain with me, but still it is showing the same error and not forwarding user to https://www.

Comment: I have already explained in my answer. You can only do that with a valid certificate for non-www. Please read my answer.